# Is there a way to do the same as Split Lines at Points (ArcGIS tools) using Python but preserving the curvature of the lines?

Tags: python, arcgis, shapely, arcpy

I want to split a line in the locations of the points (which are actually the vertex of the lines, but I would like to make it more generic and use user given points) and preserve the curvature -if any- of the lines.

I don't have ArcGIS advanced license so I would like it to be in a python script that uses only arcpy for basic license, and any other free packages. Also, the code should always be reading feature classes and not shape files, as these ones changes the curves.

I would like it to be like this: Highlighted cyan [1] segment is split from the other segments based on the points [2] and the curvature is preserved. Unlike purple segment, where the split happened but the curvature was lost.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lysnZ.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmnLy.png)

Here is a snippet of my code for splitting lines at points, which is currently not working for many issues.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, MultiLineString
import arcpy

# Set up input feature classes
lines_fc = r"C:\test\test.gdb\lines"
points_fc = r"C:\test\test.gdb\points"

# Define a function to extract x and y coordinates of each vertex of a line
def get_line_vertices(line_geometry):
    x_coords = []
    y_coords = []
    for part in line_geometry:
        for point in part:
            x_coords.append(point.X)
            y_coords.append(point.Y)
    return x_coords, y_coords

# Open a search cursor on the lines feature class
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lines_fc, ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        line_geometry = row[0]
        x_coords, y_coords = get_line_vertices(line_geometry)

        # loop through the features in the points feature class and split the line
        points = []
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points_fc, ["SHAPE@"]) as point_cursor:
            for point_row in point_cursor:
                shapely_point = Point(point_row[0].firstPoint.X, point_row[0].firstPoint.Y)
                points.append(shapely_point)

        # Create a MultiLineString object containing the original line and the split lines
        multiline = MultiLineString([line_geometry])

        for point in points:
            if point.within(line_geometry):
                split_lines = multiline.cut(point)
                # Create a new feature class from the split lines
                arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(arcpy.env.workspace, "_splitted", "POLYLINE", lines_fc)
                with arcpy.da.InsertCursor("_splitted", ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
                    for split_line in split_lines:
                        cursor.insertRow([LineString(split_line.coords)])
```

I attempted the same using a code I found online which splits the line at vertices of the line itself (which is what I aim at the end) but I lost the curvatures since the code at the end what it does is to connect with a straight line the points.

```
import arcpy
import os
# Input feature class (lines)
inFc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# Output name feature class, will be created by the script
outFc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outPath, outName = os.path.split (outFc)
outFc = arcpy.CreateUniqueName (outName, outPath)
outPath, outName = os.path.split (outFc)
outFc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (outPath, outName, "POLYLINE", inFc,
                                             spatial_reference = inFc) [0]
flds = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields (inFc)]
flds = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields (outFc) if f.name in flds] + ["SHAPE@"]
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (outFc, flds) as iCurs:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (inFc, flds) as sCurs:
        for row in sCurs:
            row = list (row)
            geom = row [-1]
            if not geom:
                iCurs.insertRow (row)
                continue
            for i in range (geom.partCount):
                part = geom.getPart (i)
                fPoint = None
                count = part.count
                for c in range (count):
                    if fPoint == None:
                        fPoint = part.getObject (c)
                        continue
                    lPoint = part.getObject (c)
                    ln = arcpy.Polyline (arcpy.Array ([fPoint, lPoint]))
                    row [-1] = ln
                    iCurs.insertRow (row)
                    fPoint = lPoint
```